# Mailchimp keeps revoking/disabling my API key

Tags: node.js, express

Mailchimp keeps revoking/disabling my API key when I try to use the signup form in my Node.js/Express app deployed with cyclic.sh. I received a mail from mailchimp that my API key was posted publicly online because I host my code on GITHUB and the repository is public. So how do I get around this and stop my API key from being disabled? Am I suppose to somehow encrypt my key or something?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");


const https = require("https");

const { response } = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    const firstName = req.body.fName;
    const lastName = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;

    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME: lastName
                },
            }
        ]
    }
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = "https://****.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/**********"
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        auth: "ch****s1:cf3b3175*********************be29-****"
    }

    const request = https.request(url, options, function (response) {
        var statCode = response.statusCode;
        if (statCode === 200) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
        }
        else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
        }


        response.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));

        });
    });
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();
});

app.post("/failure", function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this is happening is because your API key is meant to be private as anyone who access to the API key can do some damage (In this case tamper or delete your contacts on Mailchimp). In your code the API is visible which triggers a safety mechanism in Mailchimp which ultimately revokes/disables your API key.

The best practice (On localhost) is to create a `.env` file where you store your API key or any other sensitive information.

Now you can paste your API key in the `.env` file like this

```
API_KEY = YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can then request for it using

```
process.env.API_KEY
```

Note that you have to install the `dotenv` package and require in your code.

**Note that the above process only works locally and is just a convention that is ideally followed.**

---

**To make this work on the server**

*assuming you are starting to read from here*

Make the above-stated changes to your code.
Make sure to create a `.gitignore` and specify the path to the `.env` file so that it does not get uploaded to GitHub.

And now, you will simply have to set an environment variable called `API_KEY` while deploying.

---

Check-out this video I used for reference [Hiding API Keys with Environment Variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17UVejOw3zA)

Answer (score 0):

So what to include in auth as an `API_KEY` after hiding it in `.env` file??

```
const options = {
  method: 'post',
  auth: 'Zzz1:YOUR-API-KEY'
};
```